# Question about proof that every probability measure on a metric space is regular

Tags: real-analysis, probability, analysis, measure-theory, weak-convergence

I have a question from the first proof in Billingsley's Convergence of Probability measures. In the following proof, why does the result follow from showing that $\mathcal{G}$ is a $\sigma$-field?

> Theorem 1.1. Every probability measure $P$ on the metric space $(S, \mathcal{S})$ is regular; that is, for every $\mathcal{S}$-set $A$ and every $\epsilon$ there exist a closed set $F$ and an open set $G$ such that $F \subset A \subset G$ and $P(G-F)<\epsilon$.
>
> Proof. Denote the metric on $S$ by $\rho(x, y)$ and the distance from $x$ to $A$ by $\rho(x, A)[\mathrm{M} 1] .{ }^{\S}$ If $A$ is closed, we can take $F=A$ and $G=A^{\delta}=[x: \rho(x, A)<\delta]$ for some $\delta$, since the latter sets decrease to $A$ as $\delta \downarrow 0$. Hence we need only show that the class $\mathcal{G}$ of $\mathcal{S}$-sets with
> the asserted property is a $\sigma$-field. Given sets $A_{n}$ in $\mathcal{G}$, choose closed sets $F_{n}$ and open sets $G_{n}$ such that $F_{n} \subset A_{n} \subset G_{n}$ and $P\left(G_{n}-F_{n}\right)<$ $\epsilon / 2^{n+1}$. If $G=\bigcup_{n} G_{n}$, and if $F=\bigcup_{n \leq n_{0}} F_{n}$, with $n_{0}$ so chosen that $P\left(\bigcup_{n} F_{n}-F\right)<\epsilon / 2$, then $F \subset \bigcup_{n} A_{n} \subset G$ and $P(G-F)<\epsilon$. Thus $\mathcal{G}$ is closed under the formation of countable unions; since it is obviously closed under complementation, $\mathcal{G}$ is a $\sigma$-field.

Comment: Probably $\mathcal S$ is a Borel $\sigma-$field, right? The idea is simple. Denote $\mathcal L$ the class of those sets $A$ such that for every $\varepsilon$ there exist a closed set $F$ and open set $G$ such that $F \subset A \subset G$ and $\mathbb P(G \setminus F) < \varepsilon$. If only we know that $\mathcal L$ is $\sigma-$field and that $\mathcal L$ contains every closed set, then $\mathcal L$ must contain a $\sigma-$field generated by closed sets (that is, Borel $\sigma-$field).